# extract data using regexp in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

In the tutorial of http://tryregex.com/ i faced the question below:

Write a regular expression which extracts everything between the opening bracket and the closing bracket of the shortStory variable (note that you can view the contents of the variable just by typing shortStory). Hint: you'll need the previously mentioned dot operator.

and shortStory is:

```
"A regular expression (also regex or regexp) is a string."
```

I wonder which method in javascript can extract data using regexp? something like SOMEMETHOD in below:

```
var pat = /\(.+\)/;
shortStory.SOMEMETHOD(pat);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) :

`exec` : A `RegExp` method that executes a search for a match in a string. It returns an array of information.

`test` : A `RegExp` method that tests for a match in a string. It returns true or false.

`match` : A `String` method that executes a search for a match in a string. It returns an array of information or null on a mismatch.

`search` : A `String` method that tests for a match in a string. It returns the index of the match, or -1 if the search fails.

`replace` : A `String` method that executes a search for a match in a string, and replaces the matched substring with a replacement substring.

`split` : A `String` method that uses a regular expression or a fixed string to break a string into an array of substrings.

The last 4 follow this format: `String.method(regex)`

edit: Here's an example -

```
'fat car'.search(/(car)/)
```

this returns `4`

```
'fat car'.replace(/(car)/, 'fish')
```

this returns `"fat fish"`

```
'fat car'.match(/(car)/)
```

this returns `["car", "car"]`

```
'fat car'.match(/(cat)/)
```

this returns `null`

Comment: I think an example of these would help OP, but yes OP these are the javascript methods that support regular expression.

Comment: OP asks for a method to "extract" data using regex, I think he wants .match() specifically.

Comment: Added an example for that as well :)

Comment: take a visit to the url, it won't solve by these funcs, already khonw

Comment: what exactly are you trying to get?

Comment: That's because your regex is incorrect. You're using `(` and `)` without escaping them when you want to use them literally. Replace your regex with `/\(.+\)/` and it'll match what you want.